# Can't plot a linear regression in R using effect_plot(): value for 'data' not found in R while

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a simple linear regression model using jtools::effect_plot(model) but I always get an error message like: "Error: The variable(s) were not found in the data" or "Error: value for 'grade' not found".

I've looked at the documentation of the jtools but still don't realize what is missing.

```
library(jtools)
library(ggplot2)

model <- lm(grade ~ hours_studied, data = data) #or
model2 <- lm(data$grade ~ data$hours_studied)
effect_plot(model)
effect_plot(model2)
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you haven't defined `data`. You need to define or import a dataframe that has columns `grade` and `hours_studied`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(data.table) 
library(jtools) 
library(ggplot2)
model <- lm(grade ~ hours_studied, data = data)
effect_plot(model, pred= hours_studied)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the effect_plot() function, you need to provide a value for the argument 'pred' as it does not have a default one.

Please refer to documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jtools/versions/2.1.0/topics/effect_plot